# Adding a -q switch to a list of arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am trying to figure a way to add an optional quiet switch to my command line arguments. The program I'm working on is a text to HTML converter, and at minimum requires a text sourcefile to be included in order for the program to run. What I am trying to get, is when a user enters -q anywhere in the argument list, the program will still run but suppress the output to the console. I have tried a few if statements and loops that will re assign argument values to my infile and outfile variables but those are not working either. The code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab8ecfd09bddba0d4fcc. I am still relatively new to working with C++ so if you provide an explanation as to how to get closer to my goal in a simple way, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Would getopt or something similar be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something jumped out at me right away, you're testing if the argument equals `-q` by

```
if( strcmp( argv[1], "-q" ) != 0) //This is an example of what I am trying to do.
{
    quiet = true;
    infile.open( argv[2] );
}
```

which is incorrect. strcmp returns the lexical difference between the two strings compared : 
    http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

so I believe you want

```
if( strcmp( argv[1], "-q" ) == 0) //This is an example of what I am trying to do.
{
    quiet = true;
    infile.open( argv[2] );
}
```

Like I said, I haven't tested anything, it just jumped out at me.

**edit**

how I would parse in the sourcefile, destfile, and -q option

```
std::string sourceFile;
std::string destFile;

if ( argc == 3 )
{
    sourceFile = std::string( argv[1] );
    destFile = std::string( argv[2] );
}
else if ( argc == 4 )
{
    // quiet mode is enabled
    std::string arg1( argv[1] );
    std::string arg2( argv[2] );
    std::string arg3( argv[3] );

    if ( arg1 != "-q" )
        vec.push_back( std::string( arg1 );
    if ( arg2 != "-q" )
        vec.push_back( std::string( arg2 );
    if ( arg3 != "-q" )
        vec.push_back( std::string( arg3 );

    if ( vec.size() != 2 )
    {
        // maybe error? 
    }
    else
    {
        sourceFile = vec[0];
        destFile = vec[1];
    }
}
```

Certainly not as clean as possible, and I haven't tested it so there may be a small error.

Comment: Ah I believe I am on the right track now, I can't believe I missed that. I think I have gotten it closer to working now. Thanks. One other question, for my string outfilename, is it possible to assign different command line arguments to it depending on when the -q switch is entered? Is there a function I can use to assign a char* of an argument to a string?

Comment: each `char*` of argv is null-terminated, so it can be passed directly into the constructor of an `std::string` : 

    `std::string s( argv[2] )`

or whichever arg you want. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Somewhat. What I mean is will I have to recreate the string outfilename each time the quiet switch is in a different position in the argument list or can I pass it in by doing outfilename( argv[3] ) for example?

Comment: So are you saying what should you do when they don't provide the -q option? personally, I would expect the -q option at position 1 of argv. If it's there, then I know that sourcefile is at position 2 and destfile is at position 3, `else` I know that sourcefile is at position 1 and destfile is at position 2. So I would read everything in according to that logic, and then be done with the argument list.

Comment: Where does the vector come in and what exactly is it used for? Just to convert the C style args to C++ strings? Or is it for something else?

Comment: honestly, it's just for convenience. Without making a list of the arguments, you're going to end up with some nasty if statements. I also used it to verify that there were exactly two arguments that were not -q and exactly one argument that was -q

Comment: Okay awesome thanks for your help, I'll go work on implementing this and doing some more testing and if I have any questions I guess I'll just post here.

Comment: If you'd like you can accept my answer ( green check mark under the rating ). Only reminding you because you are new.